# Como declarar variáveis no for em c?

Tags: c

Ele da erro, quando tento declarar uma variável em um laço como for, while.
Antes eu conseguia, tem a ver com a versão da linguagem?

Comment: O ideal seria que você colocasse o seu código na pergunta para vermos o que está errado.

Comment: Não tem código, só que ele da erro.

Comment: Mas dá erro onde se não tem código? rs..

Comment: creio que porque está usando a versão c99, ja tinha configurado o codeblocks uma vez e ele funcionava.

Comment: Não sei o que é pior, se é a pergunta sem exemplo, ou as respostas que explicam pra fazer exatamente o contrário da pergunta. @user41625 seria legal ao menos [edit] e por um exemplo de como funcionava antes, pra que o pessoal responda o que precisa ser feito pra continuar funcionando. Ou você mesmo testar e responder, já que pelo comentário do C99, matou a charada. Lembre-se que uma pergunta bem formulada atrai respostas mais objetivas, e ajuda a mais pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

Comment: O pior é este comentário: `Não tem código, só que ele da erro.` @Bacco

Comment: @Bacco o pior é ter 3 votos positivos em nada. principalmente porque é raro um boa pergunta de C ter 3 votos.

Comment: Foi mal, consegui resolver.

Comment: @user41625 mesmo assim, seria legal vc por o código que usou e não deu certo na pergunta, e postar uma resposta mostrando como resolveu, isso poderia ajudar outras pessoas. Note que quando comentamos sobre problemas na pergunta, não é pra te criticar, e sim para apontar como é que você pode melhorar sua postagem.

Comment: Use essa macro que com certeza vai funcionar `#define FOR(x,y) int x; for(x=0;x<y;x++)` o jeito de usar fica: `FOR(i,5){ puts("string"); }`. Obs: como a macro já faz a declaração da variável, não da para usar a mesma variável dentro do mesmo método, então não se acostume a usar essa macro.

Answer (score 1):

Na linguagem C89, é obrigatória a declaração das variáveis no início de um bloco de código. Sempre após um abre "{". Seja dentro de um if ou no início do método.

Pode ser que antes você conseguia porque o compilador que você usava não utilizava as mesmas regras que o seu atual compilador (tem compiladores que não seguem só as regras do C89 e aceitam extensões como as GNU. Com isso, é possível declarar variáveis fora de ordem).

Agora ele não deve ser mais já que parou de funcionar. Ou você passou a passar pra ele a flag -pedantic, que instrui o compilador a seguir o padrão ao pé da letra.

Para evitar esse problema, remova o flag, mude o compilador ou declare int i no começo do bloco e use no for ou volte o código pra que o for seja a primeira operação.

```
int i = 0;

...

for( ; i < SIZE; i++ )
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declara antes do FOR, e no for chama a variável declarada

Answer (score 1):

embora a pergunta não seja muito detalhada você pode fazer assim:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  /* seu código aqui*/
```

ou dessa maneira se a variável é dentro do laço:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   int j = 2;
   printf("%d\n", i*j);
}
```